# Curl request with certificate is failing

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to get some data from certain server. I was sent a .pfx certificate and was told to use it along with my username and password in order to establish connection. After reading online, I found out that I needed to convert the .pfx certificate into .pem which I did using a password that I was given along with the certificate. I'm trying now to establish connection using the following curl call:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$account:$passw");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,getcwd() . "/application/controllers/my_cert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAPATH,getcwd() . "/application/controllers/my_cert.pem");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo curl_errno($ch);
echo "\n\n";
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but haven't had any success. I tried also the following alternate call with no success either:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$account:$passw");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . "/application/controllers/my_cert.pem");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo curl_errno($ch);
echo "\n\n";
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm getting a 503 error (Service Temporarily Unavailable). When printing out the error: curl_error(): 74 is not a valid cURL handle resource
I've contacted the people in charge of the server just to verify the service and the server are up and running correctly and everything seems fine on their side.

Comment: Did you verify that they have SSL running on their side?

Comment: @Difster yes sir, I did

Comment: You might ask them for their logs as it relates to your requesting IP then.